# Does Pycharm 3.0 support JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pycharm

How can I enable JavaScript plugin in Pycharm 3.0?

I cannot find "JavaScript" plugin in the repository (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/index?pr=&category_id=50).

Answer (score 9):

As you can find in the [PyCharm Editions Comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), JavaScript support is available only in the Professional edition.

Professional edition has JavaScript plug-in bundled and you don't need to install it separately. There is no JavaScript plug-in for the Community edition.

Answer (score 2):

## No

[image]

from http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/file-types-recognized-by-pycharm.html

But it shows that CSS should be supported, which I was wondering about:
[image]